# Microdata and replacing entities for display

Tags: html5, microdata, schema.org

The question is about using Microdata to replace entities inside the Schema.org properties `description` or `articleBody`:

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. (<a href="http://winchdesign.com" target="_blank">winchdesign.com</a>)</p>
```

if we replace entities it will show:

```html
&lt;p&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.  (&lt;a href=&quot;http://winchdesign.com&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;&gt;winchdesign.com&lt;/a&gt;)&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;(&lt;a href=&quot;http://robbreport.com&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;&gt;robbreport.com&lt;/a&gt;)&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;
```

Is that allowed in Microdata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Schema.org properties [`articleBody`](http://schema.org/articleBody) and [`description`](http://schema.org/description) expect *Text* as value. If you want to follow this advice, you have to specify the properties (in `itemprop`) on an element that creates a [string value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27871012/1591669) (these are most elements, e.g., `div`).

So let’s say you use `<div itemprop="articleBody"></div>`. It’s the *textContent* of that element that will be used as value.

#### First example

```html
<div itemprop="articleBody">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. (<a href="http://winchdesign.com" target="_blank">winchdesign.com</a>)</p>
</div>
```

It generates this property value:

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. (winchdesign.com)
```

As you can see, this is readable text. This is what you probably want to provide.

#### Second example

```html
<div itemprop="articleBody">
  &lt;p&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.  (&lt;a href=&quot;http://winchdesign.com&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;&gt;winchdesign.com&lt;/a&gt;)&lt;/p&gt;
  &lt;p&gt;(&lt;a href=&quot;http://robbreport.com&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;&gt;robbreport.com&lt;/a&gt;)&lt;/p&gt;
  &lt;p&gt;&nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;
</div>
```

It generates this property value:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. (<a href="http://winchdesign.com" target="_blank">winchdesign.com</a>)</p> <p>(<a href="http://robbreport.com" target="_blank">robbreport.com</a>)</p> <p> </p>
```

As you can see, this text contains parts that *look like* HTML, but they will be interpreted as plain text (!). So this probably not what you want to provide.

To give a clearer example:

- `<span itemprop="name">John</span>`: The `name` is "John".
- `<span itemprop="name"><b>John</b></span>`: The `name` is "John".
- `<span itemprop="name">&lt;b&gt;John&lt;/b&gt;</span>`: The `name` is "<b>John</b>".

Comment: That  @unor is a  very clear explanation I really appreciate it , but what about JSON-LD 

What if, I pass the html tags there???  

Thanks

Comment: @Locke: If embedded in HTML, I guess the same rules should apply, i.e., whatever are the rules for `script` elements (ref. the thread [HTML Entities and Escaping in JSON-LD Literals](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-schemaorg/2015Jun/0034.html) and the spec section [Embedding JSON-LD in HTML Documents](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-json-ld-20140116/#embedding-json-ld-in-html-documents)), but I didn’t look into it. (Anyway, would be a topic for a separate question.)

Comment: Well , in the mean time , Yandex din't pass the test , but I get everything green in Google . Let's wait to see what does webmaster tools have to say.