# Should itemprop be on innermost HTML tag?

Tags: html, microdata

I wonder if it makes any difference whether I markup an item on my site like this:

```html
<h1 itemprop="name"><a href="some-page.html">Joe Doe</a></h1>
```

or like this:

```html
<h1><a href="some-page.html" itemprop="name">Joe Doe</a></h1>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the element.

In your example, the `name` value isn’t the same. In the first snippet it’s the string "John Doe", in the second snippet it’s the relative URL `Joe Doe` (i.e., not what you want to convey). It’s because of the `a` element.

#### URL values

All elements that generate URL values if they have the `itemprop` attribute:

- Elements with **`src` attribute**:
  `audio`, `embed`, `iframe`, `img`, `source`, `track`, `video`
- Elements with **`href` attribute**:
  `a`, `area`, `link`
- Elements with **`data` attribute**:
  `object`

If the value is a URL, you *have* to use one of these elements.

#### Text values

All other elements generate text values. If you nest them, it doesn’t make a relevant difference on which level you specify the `itemprop` element: the value will be the textContent of all nested elements ([example in this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/90696/17633)).

But note that some of the text value elements use attributes instead of the element content, so if you specify the `itemprop` attribute on these elements, the nested elements are ignored:

- Elements with **`content` attribute**:
  any
- Elements with **`value` attribute**:
  `data`, `meter`
- Elements with **`datetime` attribute**:
  `time`

---

([per the *Microdata* Working Draft from 2018-04-26](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/WD-microdata-20180426/#values))